# Why did the door open for Ralph the second time?

Tags: once-upon-a-studio

In *Once upon a Studio*, Ralph runs into the door when trying to walk about, but then just opens it with his hand, but it didn't look like any latch was pressed.

Are there doors that have an unseen latch or something? Why was he able to open it after he ran into it when it was shut? Maybe he broke the latch when opening with his hand?

[image]

This is supposed to be a real location, maybe the actual door can give some answers.

Comment: Maybe there could be a sensor in the bar. I was going along with cartoons and cgi characters coming out of pictures up until that point. If it was purposely fake, ok.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a canon answer here. The scene relies fairly heavily on the '[rule of funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)'. It's locked because *it needs to be locked for Ralph to walk into it*. It's open because he *needs to come outside for the next part of the scene.*

We could point at the fact that the door appears to have a [mid-ba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_bar)r as a possible unlocking mechanism, that the impact may have unlocked it, or the fact that Ralph has natural '*wrecking*' skills that mean that he could easily bust any lock by leaning on it, but the reality is that it's simply a funny '[bit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtfHaJKW1zQ)'. We should apply [Bellisario's Maxim](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim) and just enjoy the physical comedy.

> "*Don't examine this too closely*".